# Generate .dll from .sym files?

Tags: dll, msys, mingw-w64

I have a .a archive compiled with MinGW from C/C++ code. I also have symbols exported in many .sym files. Now I need to generate a .dll file from their combination. I've installed MSYS/MinGW w64